# Facebook Pixel - M1

Tags: magento-1.9, facebook, facebook-pixel

My client has asked me to install Facebook pixel on there Magento 1 website. What I have received from them are the four text file
1. Add to Cart Pixel.txt
2. Initiate Checkout Pixel.txt
3. Page View Pixel.txt
4. Purchase Pixel.txt

The code inside AddTocart is

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
value: 1,
currency: 'USD',
});
</script>
```

Similar in other files also.

I have no idea how to proceed further. Where to add this code?

Can anyone suggest me on this further step?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module to fulfill your requirements. 
https://marketplace.magento.com/cadence-cadence-fbpixel.html

This will be help full for you to load script for particular pages.

for cart page, you can use this

1. Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add this :

   ```
   <checkout_cart_index>
       <reference name="head">
           <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/my-custom.js</name></action>
       </reference>
   </checkout_cart_index>
   ```

2.Create your new js file in: skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/my-custom.js then put your code inside.

3. Now your js file will be just loaded in checkout/cart. Don't forget to clear the cache.

If you want to add js in the head of checkout page then use below code

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
          <reference name="head">
               <action method="addJs"><script>product_designer/checkout_image.js</script></action>
          </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: i have recived this from my client, cant ask them to install this now.  I have to work on what they have given to me

Comment: Then you need to put it's on a particular file and need to override core files.if you install this module in your site then it will be helpful for you

Comment: Go to app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml then add this :

<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/my-custom.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
Create your new js file in: skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/my-custom.js then put your code inside.

Now your js file will be just loaded in checkout/cart. Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: What about other 3 pages? Can u tell me about that also plz

Comment: please help. I am still stuck

Comment: If you want to add js in the head of checkout page then use below code

    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
              <reference name="head">
                   <action method="addJs"><script>product_designer/checkout_image.js</script></action>
              </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

Comment: I have recived this statement in instruction doc. "Please replace the "value" parameter in the snippet with the value on page." What should bt the variable name. It should show the number of products added in cart in front of value.

Comment: Yes it's the total of your cart please accept this answer if it's useful